Microsoft 365 email Login for Web Application ( Flask)
I am making a web application for my university project, and since our university's email is based on Microsoft 365, i wanted to find a way to integrate a way to login using the 365 email.
How do I integrate Microsoft 365 login into my web app without using my university email to create the application in azure?
I have created a Microsoft azure application with my personal email (because my university does not allow me to create an application using the university email) and set it up in my flask app, but when i wanted to login with the email that i created the app with, and also my university email, it  says "Selected user account does not exist in tenant 'Microsoft Services' and cannot access the application 'this is the tenant id' in that tenant. The account needs to be added as an external user in the tenant first. Please use a different account."
